# Best way to print orders within EE Store?

Tags: expresso-store

Have a couple of stores using Expresso Store; just built a new one and the client asked how they should print the order details out. I think the other two stores just copy and paste the order details but their sites are a few years old, and I think expectations have changed since then.

In Shopify, for example, earlier this year we setup the Order Printer plugin for a client and created a really nice template they could print out, cut off one bit to go on the parcel, and the other to go inside the parcel.

How does everyone else do this in Store? I'm specifically talking about within the control panel.

Comment: Store has several PDF options, if you visit an order detail page you should see a PDF button top right. If you have the necessary facilities installed you should be able to send it directly to your printer.

Comment: We felt we didn't want the payment section of the order details shown to the customer, which is included by default with the Export As PDF option. I suppose we can just cut that bit off, actually.